# Why can't I retrieve UIDeviceOrientation correctly while playing a movie in MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer, uidevice, uiinterfaceorientation

Everything works fine while I'm not playing anything (I'm calling beginnotifications, etc, and using the orientation to rotate my view). But after I start playing with `MPMoviePlayerController` everytime when I try

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

The `orientation` gets a `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`.

Any clue?
When the movie stops everything works alright again.
I need this orientation to rotate the player's window, because Im using Iphone OS 3.1 so I can't directly use the view property inside MPMovie player controller.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found a way to do this at least in iPhone OS version lower than 3.2. I gave up.
>
> But hey, I had to code a version for my app in the Ipad and I discovered that for iPhone OS 3.2, there's a way to do it.
>
> The only thing you have to do is to use a custom class, that you have to make child of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and override the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` to return yes whenever you want the autorotation to be performed. It's all in the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` class reference.
>
> – Zelldweller